# Celery Ignoring Config Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery

Celery seems to be ignoring my config values for some reason. I have set the following values in my apps `config.py`

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"pool_recycle": 7200, 'echo': True}
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
```

however celery continues to try to connect to the following broker url `amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//`

Here is where I try to configure celery

```
def configure_extensions(app):
  # flask-sqlalchemy
  db.init_app(app)

  # marshmallow
  ma.init_app(app)

  # bcrypt
  bcrypt.init_app(app)

  #celery
  celery.config_from_object(app.config)
```

And here is my `extensions.py`

```
# Flask-SQLAlchemy extension instance
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# flask_marshmallow extension instance
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
# Bcrypt
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
# flask_restful
from flask_restful import Api
#celery
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()

db = SQLAlchemy()

ma = Marshmallow()

bcrypt = Bcrypt()

api = Api()
```

I have printed out `app.config` before calling `celery.config_from_object(app.config)` and it does include the celery values I listed above. I've looked at similar posts on stack overflow and have yet to find one that answers my question.

I am using python 3.6 and celery 4.1

Does anyone know why it is ignoring the config values? I have checked [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) and I think I am using the right values for the config

Here is a link to a minimal example repository [Github Repo](https://github.com/jrusso1020/flask-api-template)

Comment: Try `celery.config_from_object(app.config, force=True)` and see if it helps?

Comment: Are you able to show a minimal but complete example of your code that runs and shows the issue? To assist with debugging

Comment: @MattHealy I just updated the question with a minimal example of the code via a github repo

Comment: how do you start your celery workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery has a problem with Flask and the application factory pattern. Miguel Grinberg wrote a great blog post about it:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern

Essentially, you need to pass in the broker URL at the point of creation rather than defer it and update the configuration later.

I modified your `app/extensions.py` like so:

```
from celery import Celery                                                       

from . import celeryconfig                                                      
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=celeryconfig.broker_url,                       
                backend=celeryconfig.result_backend)
```

And now, running the celery worker yields the following:

```
bash# celery worker -A app.extensions

transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
```

Comment: this seems to have fixed it, thank you very much. I had actually already read the blog article but not noticed my mistake

Comment: It is a bit of disappointing that the post you cited have no explanation of the root cause, and op's method works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing prefixed with not prefixed config keys.

Just use lower case without `celery` prefix.

Also make sure to actually use the config file. I don't know what your `app` is. For importable `config_file.py` use `config_from_object('config_file')`.

Comment: this didn't seem to help, I've added a link to a minimal example github repository

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker=f'sqs://{quote(CELERY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)}:{quote(CELERY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)}@',
)

app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'queue_name_prefix': f'{ENV}-',
    'region': 'eu-central-1',
}
```

as shown in https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/t/unit/app/test_app.py#L694

Answer (score 0):

In Celery 4.0, the configuration options were changed to **lower case**, and some have been renamed. So you have to change your configuration parameters to this:

```
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
database_engine_options = {"pool_recycle": 7200, 'echo': True}
broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
```

See the [New lowercase settings](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings) section in the documentation for more detail.

Comment: this didn't help, the lowercase config variables no longer showed up in the app configuration and when moving to a separate celeryconfig.py file it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you add this line: `celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')`?